# Python finding repeating sequence in list of integers?

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have a list of lists and each list has a repeating sequence.  I'm trying to count the length of repeated sequence of integers in the list:

```
list_a = [111,0,3,1,111,0,3,1,111,0,3,1] 

list_b = [67,4,67,4,67,4,67,4,2,9,0]

list_c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,23,18,10]
```

Which would return:

```
list_a count = 4 (for [111,0,3,1])

list_b count = 2 (for [67,4])

list_c count = 10 (for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0])
```

Any advice or tips would be welcome.  I'm trying to work it out with re.compile right now but, its not quite right.

Comment: is it 100% sure that the list just contains the same repeated pattern?

Comment: Yes, there is most definitely a repeated pattern.  It could be anywhere from 1 digit to 200 digit pattern.

Comment: Regular expressions are almost certainly not what you're looking for, since you're not dealing with strings, and converting your lists into strings will, IMO, give you considerably more than 2 problems.

Comment: I have converted these lists into strings. What problems do think will happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guess the sequence length by iterating through guesses between 2 and half the sequence length. If no pattern is discovered, return 1 by default.

```
def guess_seq_len(seq):
    guess = 1
    max_len = len(seq) / 2
    for x in range(2, max_len):
        if seq[0:x] == seq[x:2*x] :
            return x

    return guess

list_a = [111,0,3,1,111,0,3,1,111,0,3,1] 
list_b = [67,4,67,4,67,4,67,4,2,9,0]
list_c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,23,18,10]

print guess_seq_len(list_a)
print guess_seq_len(list_b)
print guess_seq_len(list_c)
print guess_seq_len(range(500))   # test of no repetition
```

This gives (as expected):

```
4
2
10
1
```

As requested, this alternative gives longest repeated sequence. Hence it will return 4 for list_b. The only change is `guess = x` instead of `return x`

```
def guess_seq_len(seq):
    guess = 1
    max_len = len(seq) / 2
    for x in range(2, max_len):
        if seq[0:x] == seq[x:2*x] :
            guess = x

    return guess
```

Comment: My first comment came after I put in a list with an error.  This was really helpful and your use of the range for comparison is great :D  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Pretty sure that's not correct, at least it won't find the optimal solution. Assume `0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1` - this can be seen as a repeated sequence of 4x 2 elements or 2x 4 elements and I'd think it should find the longer sequence.

Comment: @Voo that's what I originally had but it didn't fit the sample. The answer for list_b would be 4 in that case, not 2 as specified by the author of the question.

Comment: Ah I see that one example of the author explicitly wants the shorter sequence - strange, but right you are.

Comment: I am wanting to return the longer repeated sequence.  I apologize if that wasn't made clear in my original question.

Comment: I worked it out another way but, if you want to elaborate on your original method, that be cool :)

Comment: @tijko Please see above - the left over line of `guess = 1` was a hint to first algorithms design. :)

Comment: I have been using a decrementing range -- range(len(seq),1,-1). This returns correctly for some of the patterns but, not all.

Comment: If the list is comprise of string elements then what are the changes needs to be done in the above code ?

Comment: doesn't this assume the repeating pattern begins from index 0?

Answer (score 0):

I took [Maria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/655183/maria-zverina)'s faster and more stackoverflow-compliant answer and made it find the largest sequence first:

```
def guess_seq_len(seq, verbose=False):
    seq_len = 1
    initial_item = seq[0]
    butfirst_items = seq[1:]
    if initial_item in butfirst_items:
        first_match_idx = butfirst_items.index(initial_item)
        if verbose:
            print(f'"{initial_item}" was found at index 0 and index {first_match_idx}')
        max_seq_len = min(len(seq) - first_match_idx, first_match_idx)
        for seq_len in range(max_seq_len, 0, -1):
            if seq[:seq_len] == seq[first_match_idx:first_match_idx+seq_len]:
                if verbose:
                    print(f'A sequence length of {seq_len} was found at index {first_match_idx}')
                break
    
    return seq_len
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
def repeated(L):
    '''Reduce the input list to a list of all repeated integers in the list.'''
    return [item for item in list(set(L)) if L.count(item) > 1]

def print_result(L, name):
    '''Print the output for one list.'''
    output = repeated(L)
    print '%s count = %i (for %s)' % (name, len(output), output)

list_a = [111, 0, 3, 1, 111, 0, 3, 1, 111, 0, 3, 1]
list_b = [67, 4, 67, 4, 67, 4, 67, 4, 2, 9, 0]
list_c = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 23, 18, 10
]

print_result(list_a, 'list_a')
print_result(list_b, 'list_b')
print_result(list_c, 'list_c')
```

Python's `set()` function will transform a list to a set, a datatype that can only contain one of any given value, much like a set in algebra. I converted the input list to a set, and then back to a list, reducing the list to only its unique values. I then tested the original list for each of these values to see if it contained that value more than once. I returned a list of all of the duplicates. The rest of the code is just for demonstration purposes, to show that it works.

Edit: Syntax highlighting didn't like the apostrophe in my docstring.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.