# Remove repeated sequence of integers from list in Python

Tags: python, list, sequence

I have a list of integers that I need to remove duplicate sequences from, and the logic is doing my head in.

I've been trying to modify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385718/python-finding-repeating-sequence-in-list-of-integers) to what I need, however that only returns one number pertaining to the length of the repeating sequence, and it only counts from the starting integer.

This is as far as I've gotten so far:

```
def findRep(rmRepList):
    #Array to hold [starting position, length] of repeating sequences
    repList = []
    #For each industry listed
    for industry in rmRepList:
        #Maximum starting position
        maxStartPos = len(industry)-2
        #For each possible starting point of repetition
        for start in range(1,maxStartPos):
            #Limit on how long the repetition can be
            maxLen = math.ceil((len(industry)-start)/2)

            #For each possible length (2 because already canceled out repeating resources in genAllLoop)
            for i in range(2,maxLen):
                #If the next 'i' integers repeat
                if industry[start:i+start] is industry[i+start:2*i+start]:
                    repList = [start,i]
                    industry = rmRep(repList, industry)

                #If reached end of list
                if 2*i+start+1 == len(industry):
                    #End loop
                    break

def rmRep(rmProp, loop):
    #Sequence of resources to drop
    rmSeq = [loop[rmProp[0]:rmProp[0]+rmProp[1]]]
    #Debugging statement
    print(rmSeq)
    loop.remove(rmSeq)
    return(loop)name = username_entry.get()
```

rmRepList is a list of lists, holding each list I need to analyse.

So for example, if given a list

`rmRepList = [[0,1,2,1,2,1,0],[0,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,0]]`

I would need it to return `[[0,1,2,1,0], [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0]]`

Right now, the code isn't even reaching the rmRep subroutine. I have a horrible feeling I'm going about this all wrong. I don't like that I need so many loops in the code, especially as the actual lists I have to analyse are hundreds of digits long. Is there a simpler way to do this?

---

EDIT: If it helps, I can guarantee that the lists will not repeat one integer over and over (e.g. `[0,0,0,1,0]` won't happen).

Also, the first and last number in the lists will always be the same.

Comment: Can you explain in plain English why `[0,1,2,1,2,1,0]` maps to `[0,1,2,1,0]`? The rules applied there aren't clear to me.

Comment: 1,2 is the repeated (non overlapping) sequence so it is removed

Comment: Can the duplicate sequences be any arbitrary length or just one fixed length?

Comment: Will the duplicates be right next to each other? Is ```[0,1,2,3,4,1,2]``` possible?-> which one would you remove?

Comment: ^^Duplicate sequences of arbitrary length. ^Duplicates would be right next to eachother. This still applies if you remove part of the list. e.g. `[0,1,2,3,4,3,4,2,3,4,0]` becomes `[0,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,0]` becomes `[0,1,2,3,4,0]`

Comment: So the order of extraction matters, also whether you extract longer duplicates before shorter duplicates or vis versa..?

Comment: So long that at some point there are no sequential repeating sequences (i.e. none right after each other), it works. I don't know how you would do it other than checking for sequences of all possible lengths after each step. Because of this, it shouldn't matter if you check long before short, or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the answer : detect your repeated sequences.

```
listA = [0,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,0]
listB = [0,1,2,1,2,1,0]

def get_repeated_seq(seq, start, length):
    ref = seq[start:start+length]
    #print("Ref", ref)
    for pos in range(start+length, len(seq)-length):
        compare = seq[pos:pos+length]
        #print("Pos", pos, compare)
        if compare == ref:
            print("Found", ref, "at", pos)
            return pos
    return False

def get_repeated_seqs(seq):
    for size in reversed(range(2, len(seq)/2)):
        for pos in range(0, len(seq)-size):
            print("Check rep starting at pos %s for size %s" % (pos, size))
            get_repeated_seq(seq, pos, size)

print(get_repeated_seqs(listA))
```

Then you can remove them according to your removal strategy (largests ? smallests ?)

**EDIT** : to be clear that it works (and adding some removal by the same time)

```
listA = [0,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,2,1,3,4,5,2,1,6,0]
listB = [0,1,2,1,2,1,0]

def get_repeated_seq(seq, start, length):
    ref = seq[start:start+length]
    #print("Ref", ref)
    for pos in range(start+length, len(seq)-length):
        compare = seq[pos:pos+length]
        #print("Pos", pos, compare)
        if compare == ref:
            #print("Found", ref, "at", pos)
            return pos, length
    return False

def get_repeated_seqs(seq):
    reps = []
    for size in reversed(range(2, len(seq)/2)):
        for pos in range(0, len(seq)-size):
            #print("Check rep starting at pos %s for size %s" % (pos, size))
            rep = get_repeated_seq(seq, pos, size)
            if rep:
                reps.append(rep)
    return reps

def remove_repeated_seqs(seq, reps):
    # need to backup seq ?
    for rep in reps:
        overlaps = False
        for pos in range(rep[0], rep[0]+rep[1]):
            if seq[pos] == "*":
                overlaps = True
        if not overlaps:
            for pos in range(rep[0], rep[0]+rep[1]):
                seq[pos] = "*"
    out = []
    for item in seq:
        if item != "*":
            out.append(item)
    return out


reps = get_repeated_seqs(listB)
rem = remove_repeated_seqs(listB, reps)
#print(rem)
print(rem==[0,1,2,1,0])

reps = get_repeated_seqs(listA)
rem = remove_repeated_seqs(listA, reps)
#print(rem)
print(rem==[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0])
```

outputs True and True :)

EDIT2: no -1 to go up to the end of a list in a for range loop..

Comment: Ayye, very nice! Man, the people on StackOverflow are wizards, I've been looking at this all morning and haven't gotten anywhere. I'm going to be deleting all duplicate sequences which shouldn't be too hard now. Cheers

Comment: Detecting is one thing, deleting is another :) you should be careful with overlapping removals...

Comment: for edge cases : `[0,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,2,1,3,4,5,2,1,6,0]` is a nasty sample... (2,1) is part of a (3,4,5,2,1) big sequence and is also a repeated one from (2,1)... so removing strategy have to be better defined than only "delete duplicates".

Comment: Hmm, you raise a good point. Initially, the sequences I wanted to delete were the back-to-back ones. In that case you mentioned, that would mean it becomes `[0,1,2,3,4,5,2,1,6,0]` That being said, I've just figured out that with what I already have set up, I only needed to detect lists with duplicates within them (by fluke of how I'm creating the lists in the first place), and then delete those.

Comment: Just change ListA by ListB in `print(get_repeated_seqs(listA))` and you'l get ('Found', [1, 2], 'at', 3) ???

Comment: I don't think that was it, I wasn't calling ListB by that time. Note that I was trying `[0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0]`, not `[0,1,2,1,2,1,0]` (second last digit). Regardless, I've managed to do a different method that works. It doesn't really help anyone who wants to come by later for a similar problem, as it's particular to how I'm generating the lists. If I have time later I'll try segregate it and post up my solution. Either way, your code was definitely a great place to start, so kudos for that :)

Comment: You're right !!.. the -1 in `for pos in range(start+length, len(seq)-length):` :( anyway your problem was interesting, my students will have a taste of it soon.