# How to find the repeating pattern of words in the given list of words?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of words which contains the repeating pattern e.g.

```
my_lst = ['I','Love','Python','very','much','I','Love','Python','good','nice','I','Love','Python','I','Love','Python']
```

it should return the pattern and the count

```
['I','Love','Python'], 4
```

**Edit: Pattern should have at least 2 values in sequence**

Comment: And what have you tried? What's your problem?

Comment: What pattern/patterns do you need? Most frequent? Most large? What abount order of elements?

Comment: @k0pernikus I am new to python...:-(

Comment: @DmitryFrolov Most frequent pattern.

Comment: @SubodhD Fair enough, yet these kind of "give me the code" questions are a bit frowned upon as they ask for an implemenation rather than solve a specific problem.

Comment: @SubodhD pattern from 1 element - is it pattern? Please refine the problem.

Comment: @DmitryFrolov If you look at the list items you will find that a specific words are repeating in group. I want to find the count of those group of repetitions.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385718/python-finding-repeating-sequence-in-list-of-integers , modify it to your problem set. Also, do provide your solutions next time

Comment: @SubodhD can you please check my answer and let me know if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @ishaan: I have already looked at that solution, but that works with only integers not with string.

Comment: @SubodhD you added at least 2 values in sequence. How about at max ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Very important things is to know how small or large a pattern you want to look for.

Once you know your pattern length you can create bi-grams and tri-grams of those lengths and check for count.

Code to do that:

```
my_lst = ['I','Love','Python','very','much','I','Love','Python','good','nice','I','Love','Python','I','Love','Python']

min_Seq_length = 2
max_Seq_length = 3

def find_ngrams(input_list, n):
    return zip(*[input_list[i:] for i in range(n)])

all_sequences = []
for seq_length in range(min_Seq_length, max_Seq_length + 1):
    all_sequences += [val for val in find_ngrams(my_lst, seq_length)]

print(Counter(all_sequences).most_common(1)[0])
```

output:

```
(('I', 'Love', 'Python'), 4)
```

Please note that computing all n-grams is CPU and memory expensive.

Comment: But only one problem, if the word 'Python' comes in adjacent then this code doesnt work. E.g. my_lst = ['I','Love','Python','very','much','I','Love','Python','good','nice','I','Love','Python','I','Love','Python','Python'] , will not work for this list.

Comment: In that case python is the largest pattern right? with occurrence count 5. The reason people are asking you to define what patterns is because a pattern is not something that we feel should be the output. There should be a formula to define it.

Comment: You can add conditions like pattern should have at least 2 values in sequence. etc.. If you provide clear condition on what define your pattern then I can change code accordingly to fix your problem.

Comment: @SubodhD I have updated the answer. It's very important to know your max sequence length otherwise it will be computationally expensive to do this for all possible lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Even I am new to python. This is what I came up with. Not efficient but worth considering.

```
>>> a = ['I','Love','Python','very','much','I','Love','Python','good','nice','I','Love','Python','I','Love','Python']
>>> b = ' '.join(a)
>>> print b.count(raw_input())
I Love Python
4
```

In case of finding repeating one we can take all cases in for loop and finding it.

Comment: What is raw_input() here ?

Comment: Ah it's for python 2.7. You can replace it with input() for python 3.x

Comment: So this takes user input of 'I Love Python' and then says the count of this pattern is 4 in the input list.

Comment: @Shashank: The program should identify the pattern by himself. not from the user.

Comment: Well you are interested in - How to find 'Repeating pattern' in any array ? But i am confused as if what repeating pattern you are talking about. Those pattern whose length is greater than 2 or you want include single length values too. That's why I have use input() case and left the 'finding part' for you.