# Removing list elements that repeats itself- python

Tags: python

I have an array that looks like

```
A=[0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7,0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7]
```

since the "0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7" part reapeats itself I dont need the second part so for a given array it should give me

```
A=[0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7]
```

I cant use the set() function and I dont know what else I can use in this case.Is there a function which can do this operation ?

Comment: are those duplicate sequences always come as adjacent or there could be intermediate values?

Comment: They can be totally random theres no rule, It could be like A=[4,2,9,1,3,4,0,0,7,3] and this reapets itself for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python finding repeating sequence in list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385718/python-finding-repeating-sequence-in-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the following two methods:

```
def check_repeat(l):
    for i in range(1,len(l)//2+1):
        pattern=l[:i]
        sub_lists=create_sublists(l, i, True)
        if all([x==pattern for x in sub_lists]):
            print("Found pattern {} with length {}".format(pattern, i))
            return pattern


def create_sublists(l, n, only_full=False):
    sub_lists=[]
    for j in range(n, len(l),n):
        if only_full and len(l[j:j+n])<n:
            continue
        sub_lists.append(l[j:j+n])
    return sub_lists
```

It works as follows: with `check_repeat(your_list)` the input list is checked for patterns of arbitrary length. A pattern of length `i` is found, if the first `i` entries of `your_list` equal all following sub_lists of length `i`. The sublists are created by the method `create_sublists`, which returns a list of lists. If `only_full` is set to `True`,  only sublists with length `n` are allowed. This handles the case where your list looks for example like this `A=[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2]` and you want to accept `[1,2,3]` as a valid pattern and ignore the remaining sublist `[1,2]`.

Each sublist is then compared to the current `pattern`, i.e. the first `i` entries of your input list. If all sublists, equal the current pattern, a true pattern is found.

In contrast to the solution in [Python finding repeating sequence in list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385718/python-finding-repeating-sequence-in-list-of-integers), I do not only check the next `i` entries if they match the current pattern, but all of the following sublists with length `i`.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Oooops, didn't see that you don't want to use a set. NVM, sorry.

What I would recommend doing is converting your list to a set and then back, like this:

```
A=[0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7,0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7]

S = set(A)
```

If you want to do it iteratively (, because you might want to add an extra condition):

```
S = set()
for item in A:
    s.add(item)
```

And then you can convert the set back to a list like this:

```
A = list(S)
print(A)
>>A=[0,0,1,1,2,5,6,3,7,7]
```