# How do i find repeating sequences in a list

Tags: python, string, list, sequence

Here I have a list of chords from a song. From the list it is clear that "Em, Em9, A, D" is the main chord progression and "Em, Em9" is the secondary progression. How could I extract that data from this list. Say, I had to automate and extract a 100 lists like this and get the main and secondary progressions out of it. How could I do it?

```
chords_scrape = ['Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am',
                 'D',  'Em', 'Em', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Em9', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Em', 'Em', 'Em',
                 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D',
                 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D']
```

Comment: This isn't exactly the same problem, but you might find some ideas how to proceed from this: [Python finding repeating sequence in list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385718/python-finding-repeating-sequence-in-list-of-integers)

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about music scores so this may or may not be helpful:  The Counter class (from collections) can help you get the most common patterns of a given size by feeding it every subrange of that size in the list. I believe you can determine the main and secondary progressions from that (but I wouldn't know which ones to pick myself):

```
chords = ['Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am',
                 'D',  'Em', 'Em', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Em9', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Em', 'Em', 'Em',
                 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D',
                 'Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D']

from collections import Counter
progressions = [Counter( (*chords[i:i+size],) 
                         for i in range(0,len(chords)-size+1)
                       ).most_common(1)[0]
                for size in range(5,1,-1)]
print(progressions)

[(('Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D', 'Em'), 6), 
 (('Em', 'Em9', 'Am', 'D'), 7), 
 (('Em', 'Em9', 'Am'), 7), 
 (('Em', 'Em9'), 9)]
```

*Note that Counter can also give you more than one most common if you need to pick between multiple sequences with the same frequency*

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot. I clean up the data I get from the above code.

Comment: Very nice.  Kind of fancy use of Counter with `gen-expression` here.