# Extract the indices for a set of repeating data in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of angles that always start with -90 to 90, but some of the data may have more or less values in between the start and end points. The list would look something like this:

Angles = [-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90, -90, -45, 0, 45, 90, -90, -60, -45, 0, 45, 60, 90]

I have another list with corresponding values to these angles that I want to pull without having to know the indices for the entire segment since the amount of number between the -90 and 90 may change.

For example, if we call:

Angles[0:7] that should report [-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90]

Angles[7:12] that should report [-90, -45, 0, 45, 90] and so on and so forth.

I have another list called "data" which have corresponding variables to the angles.

data = [50, 120, 0, 75, 231, 623, 30, 40, -45, 0, 3215, 955, 40, -440, -45, 210, 445, 660, 190]

Essentially I want a script that can grab the indices of all the angles and corresponding data points. It would go through the Angles variable and separate out the points from -90 to 90, then it would grab the indices (let's say Angles[0:7], Angles[7:12], etc) and would allow us to put the corresponding data points into a new variable. Segment1 = data[0:7], Segment2 = data[7:12]. I can't hardcode the exact indices since the number of points in a -90 to 90 sweep may change.

I have tried to modify one of the answers from here: [Python finding repeating sequence in list of integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385718/python-finding-repeating-sequence-in-list-of-integers) but this was using multiple lists. Could not try to understand how to use it within the same list.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what exactly your desired output is. Could you make an example of what your expected output is? And maybe show what you tried so far?

Comment: Yeah, it's unclear why the first list ends grabs values between `-90` and `-90` and the second stops at `90`, not grabbing the following `-90`. This seems like two different behaviors.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have edited the original post to clarify. I made some initial typos in the post

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit dirty logic but this is what can help you immediately

```
lsit_value = [-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90, -90, -45, 0, 45, 90, -90, -60, -45, 0, 45, 60, 90]


def test(lsit_value):
    x = 0
    couples = []
    result = []
    for i in lsit_value:
        if i == -90 :
            couples.append(x)   
        elif i == 90:
            couples.append(x)
            result.append(list(couples))
            couples.clear()
        x = x+1
    return result


print(test(lsit_value))
```

result of print [[0, 6], [7, 11], [12, 18]]